# inserting data selected by checkboxes

Tags: sql, jsp

I am trying a code where I want to create a table and insert data into the table.
I want to create table and insert data for only those fields which are selected by user using checkbox.
This is my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa","SQL1423#3");
        Statement st=null;

        String select[] = (String[]) session.getAttribute("a");
        String tblname=(String)session.getAttribute("tblname");
        //out.println(tblname);
        //String select[] = request.getParameterValues("id");
        if (select != null && select.length != 0) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) 
            {
                int ch=Integer.parseInt(select[i]);
                //int counter=1;
                //int ID=1;
                switch(ch)            
                {
                    case 1 :
                        String idOne=request.getParameter("idOne");
                        //out.println(idOne);
                        String idOneIns="insert into "+tblname+" (ID) values(?)";
                        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(idOneIns);
                        pstmt.setString(1, idOne);
                        //st=con.createStatement();
                        int valueTwo = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                        out.println("Inserted");
                        break;
                    case 2 :
                        String ser=request.getParameter("series");
                        String serIns="insert into "+tblname+" (SERIES) values(?)";
                        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(serIns);
                        pst.setString(1, ser);
                        int value = pst.executeUpdate();
                        out.println("Inserted");
                        break;
                    case 3 :
                        String sym=request.getParameter("symbol");
                        String symIns="insert into "+tblname+" (SYMBOL) values(?)";
                        PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(symIns);
                        pstm.setString(1, sym);
                        int valueOne = pstm.executeUpdate();
                        out.println("Inserted");
                        break;
                }//switch
            }//for
        }//if
        st.close();
        con.close();
    }//try
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e);
    }
%>
```

Here data is inserted in the table.But if I select all three checkboxes then data is inserted as :

```
Id   Series Symbol

1    null   null

null a      null

null null   b
```

But I want the data to be inserted as :

```
Id Series Symbol

1  a      b
```

What changes I should make so that I'll get this output?

Comment: OMG, why are you doing all that in a JSP? This is so archaic. I feel it is high time container vendors started throwing a warning/error when people use scriptlets in their JSP code.

Comment: Could you clarify your question to include the different possible input values, and the wanted results of these different inputs?

Comment: Ok. I want to give option of create table to user. There are 9 checkboxes, each represent a column of the table. Now user should be able to create the table by selecting these check boxes. Suppose he selects 3 checkboxes as ID,SERIES,SYMBOL. Then there is a form where he suppose to enter the data into textbox for these fields.  After clicking on submit the above form should execute and table for these 3 fields must be created in the database with data entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Updating the database is better put into a Controller. JSP pages is better used for displaying results (See [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern)
2. Using dynamic SQL to determine database tables is inherently dangerous and could be targeted for attacks
3. Your current code loops over input elements, and for each element inserts a new row in the database table. What you want to do is assemble the tree values (from your form input) and insert only one row. E.g.

   INSERT INTO table (ID, SERIES, SYMBOL) VALUES (?,?,?)

Comment: I am not sure that every time I'll get the same column names. Because these are the names selected by user using checkbox. And switch case is used to know which checkboxes are selected. And there are 6 more checkboxes. But for trial purpose I am using only three of them.  That is why I am using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @adarshr: I am an intern, and supposed to do the whole thing in jsp.